# Why do I get Numeric expression missing from '<EOL>'?

Tags: windbg

In my WinDbg console:

```
0:004> sxe -c "!soe System.NullReferenceException 1; .if (@$t1 == 1) { .dump /ma /u c:\tmp\NullReferenceException.dmp; gn } .else { gn }"
Numeric expression missing from '<EOL>'
```

The question is simple - why?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the exception code at the end of the line. The code is numeric - or for some exceptions has a named constant.

The syntax of the command is

```
sxe -c "" <code>
```

So in your case it should probably be

```
sxe -c "!soe System.NullReferenceException 1; 
.if (@$t1 == 1) { .dump /ma /u c:\tmp\NullReferenceException.dmp; gn } 
.else { gn }" clr
```

Note the **clr** at the end of the command.